# Save and reload a 'list' object in R

Tags: r, list, save, load

I am trying to save a list object that I manually created with some efforts into something in `list` format that I can reference back rather quickly. 
The saved object should be able to be loaded back as a `list` not `df` or anything.

Here's part of my list object down below:

```
citations <- list(
as.integer(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 111)),
as.integer(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 111)),
as.integer(c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 111)),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(111),
as.integer(6),
integer(0),
as.integer(c(14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23))
)
```

I have referenced [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893844/how-can-i-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-in-again-in-r) and a much earlier one on [nabble](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Save-amp-reload-list-objects-td4639397.html), they suggested simply using `save` and `load`, but I just couldn't figure out how this works, whenever I applied the `save()` function on the `list` object and specified an R object for it, I always got an error message.

```
save(citations, "/~citations.Rdata")
Error in save(citations, "~/citations.Rdata") : object ‘~/citations.Rdata’ not found
```

Just don't know if other function calls are needed.

Comment: The `file` argument needs to be explicit `save(citations, file 
 = "~/citations.Rdata")`

Comment: Can try `save.image(file="~/citations.Rdata")` it will save an image of the whole working env.

Comment: If you are saving a single object you may want to consider using `saveRDS` like so `saveRDS(citations, "~/citations.Rds")` and loading it with `citations <- readRDS("~/citations.Rds")`. Alternatively you can use `save` and `load` like this, `save(citations, file = "~/citations.Rdata)` and `load("~/citations.Rdata")`. You need the file argument in `save` because it expects a variable number of arguments to save.

Comment: Thanks, you all saved my day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your options are:

- `base::save` and load
- `base::saveRDS` and readRDS
- `rlist::list.save` and list.load

Comment: Old one but FWIW: I recently had an issue where `save()` worked but then `load()` just returned the name of the object as a single character item, not the object itself. `saveRDS()` worked great.